# Array comparation in javascripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I would like to compare arrays nested in arrays.

For example, I have an array like this:

```
var myArrays = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,5,6,7,2.3,4],[1,2,3,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
```

How could I know the difference length of each array from loop step by step?
I'm looking for an algorithm that will help solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Comparing the length with what ?

Comment: just length of each array from loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. It accepts as the first parameter each item in your array and will return an array **of what you will return from it**. In your case you need to return the length of your every nested array.

```js
var myArrays = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,5,6,7,2.3,4],[1,2,3,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];

var lengths = myArrays.map(arr => arr.length);

console.log(lengths);
```

For **IE**

```js
var myArrays = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,5,6,7,2.3,4],[1,2,3,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];

var lengths = myArrays.map( function(arr) { return arr.length; });

console.log(lengths);
```

Comment: consider providing a code without using arrow function, it's not supported by IE

Comment: Thanks for the edit, may I add that `.map()` is supported by IE9 not only IE11

Answer (score 0):

'data' array is a multi-dimensional array which you can iterate through it like below and find for example size of each one.

```
      for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if(data[i][j].length > 0) {
                    do sth on data[i][j]....
                }
            }
        }
```